# Calling web service when change the text in UITextField in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitextfield

I am doing something like this.

1. In my `viewdidAppear()` I am calling my web service and getting data.

   ```
   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewDidAppear(true)

       if(dm.shouldRefresh)
       {
           com.showProgress()
           self.getStaffData() { (status) in
               self.com.removeProgress()

               if(status)
               {
                   if(self.arrayDirectory != nil && self.arrayDirectory.count>0)
                   {
                       print("-----Directory data loaded----")
                       self.arrayPreviouslyLoadedArray=self.arrayDirectory

                       if(self.isfirstTime)
                       {
                           self.setupFaces()
                           self.isfirstTime=false
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           self.facesCarousel.reloadData()
                       }
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       self.addEmptyLabel()
                   }
               }
               else
               {
                   self.com.showAlertMessage()
                   self.addEmptyLabel()
               }
           }

           self.dm.shouldRefresh=false
       }
   }
   ```
2. After my table loaded, I want to perform search function on this. To search I used `UITextField`

   ```
   func searchTextFieldEditingChanged()
   {
       if(txtSearch.text != "")
       {
           self.searchText=txtSearch.text
           //NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self, selector: #selector(search), object: nil)
           self.search()
       }
       else
       {
           self.arrayDirectory=self.arrayPreviouslyLoadedArray
          facesCarousel.reloadData()
       }
   }
   ```

This works fine so far. But the problem comes when it cannot find the matching string in the current array. Initially I load 20 records from the service. And I am searching for the name "David". But this name is not included within my first 20 records. It's available in my next 20 records. But my service doesn't have a searching facility. But how can I perform this search function in normal way? Basically what I want is

1. First load 20 records
2. reload my table
3. type search query in text field
4. check whether that text available within my first 20 records
5. if available, reload my table
6. if not available take the next 20 records
7. perform the search
8. if not available take the next 20 from the service and perform the search

This is what I wanna do. And I have done up to 4th point. That means I can search a word from my first 20 records. I tried to set a flag and run the service call till its getting true.

```
func search()
{
    self.isSearching=true
    self.isfound=false
    //let exists = NSPredicate(format: "DisplayName2 CONTAINS[cd] \(searchText!)")
    let arrayTofilter:[[String:Any]]=self.arrayDirectory as! [[String : Any]]
    let aList = arrayTofilter.filter {
        ( $0 ["DisplayName2"] as! String).range(of: searchText!, options: [.diacriticInsensitive, .caseInsensitive]) != nil
    }

    if(aList.count>0)
    {
        arrayDirectory=aList
        facesCarousel.reloadData()
        isfound=true
    }
    else
    {
        repeat
        {
            self.loadAgain()
        }

        while isfound==false
    }
}
```

But this is not working as I expected. Please suggest me a better solution.
Thanks!

Comment: Please format your code. This is unreadable

Comment: @cb89 sorry. I updated

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a flag. To achieve your goal, all you need is to call search function again and again if you cannot find data. So here is the pseudo code

```
func search() {
    array.findYourObject

    if found {
        tableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        self.getStaffData() { (status) in
            array += newlyFetched20Results
            search()// You probably want to add some condition here to stop it from searching forever
        }
    }

}
```